# Mongoose Timestamp returns wrong date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a node.js REST api that reads data from a MongoDB with Mongoose, but the timestamp year is read with 1970

My Model

```
last_updated: {
    type: Date,
  }
```

my controller

```
exports.listAllGlobalData = function(req, res) {
 GlobalData.find({}).exec((err, data) => {
  console.log(data)
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(data);
   });
};
```

my data in mongodb:

```
last_updated : 1516538665
```

and the json result:

```
"last_updated": "1970-01-18T13:11:47.064Z"
```

So the time seems to be correct, but somehow the date is not as it should be 2018. The data is read only.

Comment: Could you try running the same program on a different machine?

Comment: I am, but it will take some time. I am running it at my Windows Machine at the moment but will move to Ubuntu soon.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `Date.now` as default value:

```
last_updated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
```

From the `Mongoose` docs: "`Date.now()` returns the current unix timestamp as a number."

Comment: still getting 1970 as a date

Comment: Hmm. Could be an OS issue then.

Answer (score 2):

So the issue was with **timestamp format** after all, which is in seconds, while `Date` (which mongoose uses) expects it in **miliseconds**. Quite trivial after all.

I ended up using [`SchemaType.prototype.set` on attribute with function as value](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-set), which checked the timestamp length, multiplying it by 1000 if its in seconds (shorter).

You can also do it before populating the model, but this way there is no need for doing it everytime, except of setting the same key to Schema attributes that are `typeof Date`.
It can also be done with arrow function e.g.:

> `set: v => Math.round(v)`

I dont know if this is the best approach, nor if there is a way to add this function to when attribute parameter `Schema.Types.Date` is declared

Also i couldnt use hooks to events like `save` or `update`, cause i dont call any of these methods on this model